# Upload file with cypress not working in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, automation, cypress, ui-testing

I'm using cypress-file-upload in my test to upload a file using drag and drop option. It is working fine when I run my test locally. However, when trying to run the same test in Jenkins pipeline the test is failing at upload stage. Since I cannot see the behaviour I'm confused on the issue caused here. Below is my sample code.

```
uploadFile(){
          const filePath = "FILE_1.ab"
          cy.get('[data-cy="file-upload"]').attachFile(filePath, {subjectType: 'drag-n-drop'});
}
```

FYI- It's running locally but not in Jenkins. Any idea ?

Comment: You need to get to some error and share it here, this is unanswerable. Do you have the file in the pipeline?

Comment: I have the file under fixtures and it's under my repository .So I assume it will locate the file and upload when running through jenkins.